# $\int_0^1 xf(x)\,dx \le \int_0^1 \frac{2}{3}f(x)\,dx$ for a concave function $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $f$ be a concave function (therefore continuous) on $[0,1]$. I want to prove that $\int_0^1 xf(x)\,dx \le \int_0^1 \frac{2}{3}f(x)\,dx$ and find the condition when $=$ holds.

I have tried using Riemann Sums, LHS is the limit of $\sum_i \frac{i}{n^2} f(\frac{i}{n})$ and RHS is the limit of $\sum_i \frac{2i}{3n} f(\frac{i}{n})$, but I don't know how to continue (this may not work).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729244/f-convex-g-concave-and-increasing-int-01-f-int-01-g-then-int-0/2729305#2729305 Here's a proof - see the lemma.

Comment: Actually there are concave functions on $[0,1]$ that are not continuous.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Assume $f(0)\ge 0$.

First, integrate by parts with $u=x$ and $v=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$.

Then, use $\int_0^x f(t)\,dt\ge \frac12 xf(x)$ for any concave $f(x)$.

Comment: Nice hint! +1 given days ago.

Comment: @zhw. Thank you as always!

Answer (score 3):

This is false as it stands, $f(x)\equiv -1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Sorry I fogot the condition that $f$ is nonnegative

Comment: @TiWen When were you thinking about editing your question to reflect that?

Comment: (+1) for the trivial counterexample to the original statement.

Comment: @MarkViola This is getting embarrassing, I've got as many points as you do now. Shoulda been a comment. Actually it still is a counterexample since the OP didn't edit.

Comment: @zhw. I'm not sure why the OP hasn't edited after all of the feedback.  Curious.